# get dropdown selected value

Tags: html, xslt, select

i have the following script for dropdown

```
<xsl:element name="optgroup">
    <xsl:for-each select="$parent/child::node">    
        <xsl:element name="option">
            <xsl:attribute name='Value' >
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>    
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
```

i am selecting one element out of 10 elements. how to get the value of selected element on `input[type=button]` click event?

Comment: S: From where we can obtain such information as the **"selected element"**? If this is some kind of specific XSLT environment with specific variable bindings or extensions functions such as Umbraco, etc., then you need to clarify and retag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have posted a snippet of XSLT and tagged the question as XSLT but reacting on click events in a HTML document is a job for client-side script, not for XSLT.
Assuming your `optgroup` element is part of a `select` element with `name="select1"` and both the `select` and the `input` button are inside of a `form` with `name="form1"` you can use e.g.

```
<input type="button" 
       value="..." 
       onclick="alert(this.form.elements.select1.value);"/>
```

to alert the selected value.